# Download a .rar from a website, unzip it and place it on a folder

Tags: file, batch-file, download

Hello i was trying to download a `.zip` file from a website but it doesnt seem to work it the file doesnt get to the specific folder
"c:\potato"

Here is my code:

```
@Echo off
echo download press any key
pause
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "JobName"
http://download1142.mediafire.com/sxd533x3fosg/ymr5y2r0yax2fx8/minecraft+generator.zip C:\Potato.exe
pause
```

Comment: run it with `echo on` to see any errormessages.

Comment: Do you have permission to download directly to C:?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "infile=http://download1142.mediafire.com/3b1mz9yb72tg/ymr5y2r0yax2fx8/minecraft+generator.zip"
set "outfile=Potato.zip"
cd "C:\"
echo download press any key
pause
powershell.exe -Command (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('"%infile%"','"%outfile%"') | findstr "Exception error" >nul 2>nul
set "downloadComplete=%errorlevel%"
if %downloadComplete% neq 1 echo Something went wrong, please try again
if %downloadComplete% neq 1 pause
if %downloadComplete% neq 1 goto :eof
unzip "%outfile%" "minecraft generator.zip" >nul
unzip "minecraft generator.zip" "minecraft generator.exe" >nul
rename "minecraft generator.exe" "potato.exe"
pause
```

Please note that you used the mediafire URL instead of the actual file URL, and that you try to download a zip file to .exe. You should first download the file as zip, and then use unzip to unzip the files.

Also note that your second zip seems to be password protected.